# Porque el JButton esta declarado bien pero no lo veo?

Tags: java, netbeans

Declare un JButton dentro de mi JFrame pero luego la saque afuera,
especificamente aqui:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que ahi habia una paleta de componentes y pense que al dejarlo ahi se iria a eliminar, pero no, se desaparecio y sigue declarado, y ahora quiero eliminarlo pero no se donde, desde codigo no me deja ya que como ven no declare el Jframe por mi cuenta en codigo, no puedo volver a atras porque justamente lo apague, y al volver intente eliminar la paleta de componentes y no lo encontre y aparte tampoco se como devolver la paleta, lo googlie pero no me aparece nada.

Comment: Selecciona *Window > Navigator*, haz click sobre la ventana de diseño. En el Navigator deberás ver tu botón bajo **Other Components**. Para mostrar la paleta selecciona *Window > IDE Tools > Palette*.

Comment: Oye de veras muchas gracias! De momento me habia tocado utilizar el add from palette desde algun componente